# Debug responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools

How do I debug reponsive design problems? How reliable is Chrome devTools for testing if everything is fine?

I use devTools all the time, but now... I am not sure anymore how good it actually is, since I don't have real devices for testing and comparing. For example, for front page ( www.plantea.com.hr ) on viewport rendering for Iphone 4 it seems allright, but on that actual mobile device it seems like page width isn't set 100%, there is padding or margin or something on right side and I can't tell what is causing the problem. Also, some heading tags don't show proper font-family.

Same thing is when I check on websites like http://www.responsinator.com/?url=www.plantea.com.hr or http://mobiletest.me/ Everyhing seems just fine while in reality it isn't.

Comment: Retina displays, my brother, they change pixel ration. Check [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/) out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In short

Some things can be accomplished with dev tools, but it's not an alternative to testing on real devices.

#### Not so short

DevTools do the best to test things like CSS Media Queries and they recreate the device size and touch event, but they don't go beyond that.

Next step?
There are few options for testing in the industry now: emulators, virtual machines, testing services like [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/). But while testing services are great at showing what your website looks like, they will never be as good as testing your code on actual devices.

Emulators and testing services are more efficient than buying and maintaining your own device lab, and they really help you to understand how your code behaves on different platforms, but they don’t tell you everything you need to know about the UX.

#### Further reading

- [Prioritizing Devices: Testing And Responsive Web Design](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/07/14/testing-and-responsive-web-design/)

Comment: Browserstack seems to display bug properly. But how do I go about finding out what is the problem/what to fix?

Comment: Well, the problem for sure is with the media queries when `max-width: 767px`, so try first to identify the problem adding removing styles in the element who has the problem, also it's important to know how Bootstrap rows and containers works, if you show an screenshot and some HTML would be better to get help (next time)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried emulation mode? Go to Dev tools and in the top let next to the magnifying glass there is something that looks like a phone, click it and you are in emulation mode. Then you can select which device below in the console. It may not be perfect but might help. You can also try the add-on for chrome called Resolution Test. If that doesn't work, maybe a service like browserstack.com

Comment: Yeah, I was referring to emulation mode which fails to display page properly like on real device.